# Ordering for Tuple_2 in scala by keys

Tags: scala, collections

I use `SortedMap` as follows:

```
class Cls
val m = SortedMap[Long, Cls]()

def m = {
    val v = m.max._1 //no implicit ordering defined for (Long, Cls)
    //do some with it
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to define `Ordering` for the `Map` using Ordering of keys (`Long` in my case)?

Comment: I know this is not the question, but you could use `m.maxBy(_._1)._1`, or even, using the fact that your `Map` is already sorted `m.last._1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Ordering.by](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/math/Ordering$.html#by[T,S](f:T=%3ES)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[S]):scala.math.Ordering[T]) to create an `Ordering[T]` based from a function `T => S` and an `Ordering[S]`.

```
Ordering.by((t: (Long, Cls)) => t._1)
```

Will get you an ordering based on the first field of the tuple.  An Ordering[Long] is implicitly available so there is no need to provide it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the one define in [`scala.math.Ordering` companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/math/Ordering$.html#Tuple2[T1,T2](implicitord1:scala.math.Ordering[T1],implicitord2:scala.math.Ordering[T2]):scala.math.Ordering[(T1,T2)]) by importing `scala.math.Ordering._`. For reference, here is the implementation:

```
implicit def Tuple2[T1, T2](implicit ord1: Ordering[T1], ord2: Ordering[T2]): Ordering[(T1, T2)] =
  new Ordering[(T1, T2)]{
    def compare(x: (T1, T2), y: (T1, T2)): Int = {
      val compare1 = ord1.compare(x._1, y._1)
      if (compare1 != 0) return compare1
      val compare2 = ord2.compare(x._2, y._2)
      if (compare2 != 0) return compare2
      0
    }
  }
```

Comment: But `Tuple_2._2` is not necessary has defined Ordering.

Comment: I mean I have ordering by `Tuple2._1`. Is there a concise way to define `Ordering[Tuple2]` by `Tuple2._1`. I mean `(a, b) < (c, d)` iff  `a < c`? Maybe there is some method like in `jdk8`: `Comparator.comparing`.

Comment: Sure, either define a dummy `implicit val ord: Ordering[Cls] = new Ordering[Cls] { ... }` saying that two `Cls` are always equal, or update the definition in my answer to only use `_1`.